# How to extract the strings between two special characters using Regular Expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am totally new to regular expressions. And what I need to achieve is, I have a string variable containing the following string for example,

"My Name is #P_NAME# and I am #P_AGE# years old"

I need to extract the two strings P_NAME and P_AGE using regular expressions (to a string array or two string variables etc). i.e. the string starts with a # and ends with a # and I need to extract the middle part.

How can I do this in C# using Regular Expressions..?

And how can I extract the same above in case I have a new line character in between as well. i.e. for example,

"My Name is #P_NAME# and \r\n I am #P_AGE# years old".

Thanks

Thanks Everyone...

Following worked for me... I cannot publish my own answer as the answer until 8 hours expires in stackoverflow... :)

```
string str = "My Name is #P_NAME# and \r\n I am #P_AGE# years old";

MatchCollection allMatchResults = null;
var regexObj = new Regex(@"#\w*#");
allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(str);
```

'allMatchResults' contains #P_NAME# and #P_AGE# (i.e. including # character). But having it helps my other logics than not having it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone..

Following worked for me...

```
string str = "My Name is #P_NAME# and \r\n I am #P_AGE# years old";

MatchCollection allMatchResults = null;
var regexObj = new Regex(@"#\w*#");
allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(str);
```

'allMatchResults' contains #P_NAME# and #P_AGE# (i.e. including # character). But having it helps my other logic

Comment: Were you not assisted in finding this answer by other posters ie samjudson, ipr101 or myself?

Answer (score 31):

You can do it like this

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;

public class Test
{
        public static void Main(){
                string s = "My name is #Dave# and I am #18# years old";
                Regex r = new Regex(@"#(.+?)#");
                MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s);
                Console.WriteLine("Name is " + mc[0].Groups[1].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Age is " + mc[1].Groups[1].Value);
        }
}
```

[Demo here](http://ideone.com/HXT3u)

I don't know what your application is but I must say this is not a very robust looking data transfer method. Start getting a few extra `#`s in there and it all goes wrong. For example people with `#` in their names!

However if you can guarantee that you will always be working with a string of this format then this does work.

Explanation of Regex `#(.+?)#`

First `#` matches a `#`

`(` begins a *group*. Indexed into in `.Groups[1]` in the code. `[0]` is the whole match eg `#Dave#` not just `Dave`

`.+?` matches at least one character. `.` is a character. `+` is repetition (at least 
once). And `?` tells the regex engine to be lazy - so don't match a `#` as that will get matched by our final `#`

`)` close the group

`#` matches another `#` - the 'closing' one in this case

Answer (score 10):

A regular expression such as `"#[^#]+#"` would match a hash, followed by one or more none-hash characters, followed by another hash.

There are various alternatives that would work for this such as `"#.*?#"`.

The following code would output the #P_NAME# and #P_AGE#.

```
string p = "My Name is #P_NAME# and \r\n I am #P_AGE# years old";
Regex reg = new Regex("#[^#]+#");

MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(p);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: The `Singleline` option would only be needed if the placeholders could contain linefeeds (e.g., `#P\nNAME#`), which doesn't seem very likely.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an extension method based on this... enjoy. :)

BTW - this does not keep the # characters - something I didn't want - you can change the RegEx to those above to get that.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    ///----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the matches between delimiters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source string.</param>
    /// <param name="beginDelim">The beginning string delimiter.</param>
    /// <param name="endDelim">The end string delimiter.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <example>
    /// string beginDelim = "<span>";
    /// string endDelim = "</span>";
    /// string input = string.Format("My Name is {0}Lance{1} and I am {0}39{1} years old", beginDelim, endDelim);
    ///
    /// var values = input.GetMatches(beginDelim, endDelim);
    /// foreach (string value in values)
    /// {
    ///     Console.WriteLine(value);
    /// }
    /// </example>
    ///----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetMatches(this string source, string beginDelim, string endDelim)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex(string.Format("(?<={0})(.+?)(?={1})", Regex.Escape(beginDelim), Regex.Escape(endDelim)));
        MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(source);
        return (from Match m in matches select m.Value).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since special characters often require escaping to be treated as literal patterns, I added `Regex.Escape` for `beginDelim` and `endDelim`.

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
var results = new List<string>();
var subjectString = "My Name is #P_NAME# and \r\n I am #P_AGE# years old";
Regex regexObj = new Regex("#.+?#");
Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResults.Success) {
    results.Add(matchResults.ToString().Replace("#",""));
    matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
}
```

This should write the results to the `results` array.

Comment: Why are IgnoreCase and Multiline specified? Multiline only affects the ^ and $ characters, and there are no literal characters specified do IgnoreCase does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

No one mentioned multi-line cases, so if you have multi-line string, like:

```
var testcase = @"Here is my info
#
John Doe
18 years old
#";
var regex = new Regex(@"#(.+?)#", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var match = regex.Match(testcase);
match.Groups[1].Value.Dump();

// OR

var matches = regex.Matches(testcase);
foreach (Match m in matches) m.Groups[1].Value.Dump();

/*
Output:
John Doe
18 years old
*/
```

You need to specify the `SingleLine` flag to ignore newline characters and escape the forward slash.

*answer posted for future readers*

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
var format = "My Name is #P_NAME# and \r\n I am #P_AGE# years old";
Regex rgxp = new Regex(@"#[(?<name>\S+)\]#", RegexOptions.Compiled);
Match m = rgxp .Match(format);
if (true == m.Success)
{
   return m.Groups["name"].Value;     // <-- this statement returns the value you're looking for
}
```

Comment: -1. This answer has many problems.  For starters, the code won't even compile, and if it did, the *regex* wouldn't compile.

Comment: -1 Agreed - What is the Regex here doing? Or meant to be doing?

Comment: @el: I've noticed my typo - i missed the definition of the `format` var

Comment: @alan: I've noticed my typo - i missed the definition of the `format` var

Comment: That's a start, but the statement inside the `if` block is still just a reference--it doesn't *do* anything.  And the regex won't compile because it's got an unescaped *opening* square bracket followed by an escaped *closing* square bracket, when it doesn't need square brackets at all; `@"#(?<name>\S+)#"` is fine.  I've learned from experience to test all code before posting it here; one trivial typo can render it, not just incorrect, but incomprehensible.  And with sites like [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/6TUvu) available, there's no excuse *not* to test.

Comment: @Alan: i take your comment as a valuable feedback. are you related to the fact that my reputation went down 500 points in a single day?. As of the reference statement - i wanted to give the user the syntax to get the actual value without knowing what he/she wants to do with it. i could have simply add a statement to print to the console, but thought not needed

Comment: If you really lost 500 rep in one day, you need to take it up with the admins.  It's certainly not the result of anything *I* did.