# Regex to find items wrapped around with $()

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex that would search a string for occurrences of substring with the pattern `$(...)`. So basically anything wrapped around with `$()`. So the string

```
string str = "Hello $(item)"
```

would result true for that substring because it contains `$(item)` 
My question is how do I regex check for wrapped up items with `$(xx)` in C#?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452066/3832970

Comment: You could use `Regex.Match(str,@"\$\(.+\)").Success` to check if string contains the required item

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
var found = Regex.Match(str,@"\$\([\s\S]+\)").Success;
```

Comment: No, do not use the greedy dot. It will match too much.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated with `\s\S`

Comment: Still, that is a bad idea. Besides, see [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/285739#285739).