# How obtain the word or words into char in a String C#

Tags: c#

I need to obtain the words framed with a symbols « » in a String:

```
String phrase = "«User» of «the» application:";

String words[] = phrase.indexOf("«") + phrase.indexOf("»")

words[0] = "User";
words[1] = "the";
```

The problem is, that solution obtains only the first word: "User" and I need all the words framed...

How can I do that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7483916/3832970

Comment: You may use a loop to shift start index. `IndexOf` has an overload to specify start index.

Comment: That's right, thanks..